# What is default timeout to stop broadcast on YouTube when no streaming

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, video-streaming, tokbox

Is there any timeout to change broadcast status to "COMPLETE" from "LIVE" automatically when It's not receiving any data(stream) on YouTube.

Comment: If you check the [YouTube live FAQs](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6273849?hl=en), there is no mention of such timeout seconds. Everything is done in your encoder. YouTube will detect you stopped sending content and stop the stream for you.

Comment: I can see that it will display blank screen when it is not receiving data(stream) and broadcast never(tested for 2-3 hours) stopped.

Comment: There should be a default timeout where YouTube broadcast should be stopped when not receiving any stream.

Comment: I've reached this place when searching for "youtube stream timeouts".
Because it does just that - when my connectivity breaks for a while (power outage for more than 5-10 minutes) it just ends the stream.
I still haven't found out the exact timeout, but it definitely ends the stream at one point.

Answer (score 0):

About 30-60 minutes timeout on live events. If you don't send data within this time, they will close the event.

Comment: Do you have any documentation that might support your answer?  If so, can you please include the link?